# Robe mode: how to automatically require all submodules of the project?

Tags: ruby

After some fight, I was able to get some code completion and navigation from `robe`. Specifically, in the `*pry*` buffer I modified `$LOAD_PATH` to point at my project's source directories. However, now in order to get code navigation and completion for submodules I need to `require` all of them one by one... this seems very strange and, I hope, shouldn't be necessary...

So, what is the right way to make `robe` automatically discover all the submodules of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what kind of project you're working on.

If it's a gem, it most likely `require`-s all modules in the top-level file (the one under `lib`). `M-x inf-ruby-console-gem` will load it and in turn, all modules.

If it's a Rails project, `M-x inf-ruby-console-rails` will load Rails console. Most modules use autoloads, but `C-x C-k` should load them all using `ActionDispatch::Reloader`. That's not a sure thing, though, if you have code outside of `autoload_paths`.

If it's some other kind of project, it should have a script that launches a console with all dependencies loaded (like `bin/console`). If it doesn't you should create one. `M-x inf-ruby-console-script` will launch it.

And, to be clear, `M-x inf-ruby-console-auto` should dispatch to the most appropriate of these commands.

Comment: OK, then I'm guessing it's up to me to write the script that loads Ruby code... it's a project which is, basically, built around Cucumber tests (a testing / automation suite for another project). I'm very new to Ruby, and this question my sound very naive: the project has `env.rb` file, which seems to have infrastructural significance - is it possible that that's somehow related to `bin/console` or the likes of it?

Comment: `env.rb` is used by Cucumber IIRC, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Following Dmitry's answer, here's the `bin/console` file I ended up with:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

$:.unshift *Dir.glob('../features/support/**/').map do |folder|
 File.absolute_path(folder)
end

require 'capybara'
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'capybara-webkit' unless Gem.win_platform?
require "bundler/setup"
Bundler.require

OPTIONS = {
  :autoload_code_paths => ["features/support", "features/step_definitions"],
  :filters             => [],
  :strict              => false,
  :require             => ['../features'],
  :dry_run             => false,
  :fail_fast           => false,
  :formats             => [],
  :excludes            => [],
  :tag_expressions     => [],
  :name_regexps        => [],
  :env_vars            => {},
  :diff_enabled        => true,
  :snippets            => true,
  :source              => true,
  :duration            => true,
}

RUNTIME = Cucumber::Runtime.new(OPTIONS)
RUNTIME.send(:load_step_definitions)
RUNTIME.send(:install_wire_plugin)

require "pry"
Pry.start
```

Obviously, some sections of this file will be different for you, but they should give you a general idea of what may be in this file.  There's also the part where I tried to work around loading Cucumber's tests, but not executing them (the `RUNTIME.send() stuff). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a better way of just loading the tests.

Comment: Why load the tests, though? It's not like they contain Ruby methods that you want to use for navigation or completion. Right?

Comment: @Dmitry of course they do, this is the only code that exists in this project. Unfortunately, the code I posted above doesn't really work. It gets me half-way though because for some reason `bundle exec` does something different from just calling `ruby`...

Comment: You probably just need to add something to Gemfile.

Comment: @Dmitry actually, what I ended up doing was to recursively require all Ruby files in the project's directory. There might have been a better way of doing that, but given the insane amount of indirection in all the bundle-bundler-rbenv-shim-whatever scripts, at gave up at some point.